Launching Activity As An Independent Flow With Intent (Flutter)
I am working on a Flutter app which has an intent filter for the scheme "test". I want to be able to make intent calls from within and from external apps to this scheme and have it be independent from the running instance of the app (if present), i.e., it should get pushed on top of the external app instead of my app's MainActivity.
My app's MainActivity has the singleInstancePerTask launchMode. I have created a new Activity called IntentActivity and an intent-filter as follows:
<activity
    android:name=".IntentActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

        <data android:scheme="test"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

I tested this with the Intent Launcher app but IntentActivity opened on top of MainActivity. I also tried a sample external app but still got the same behaviour. Following is its MainActivity:
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "platform_channel"

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            when (call.method) {
                "launchTestActivity" -> {
                    val data = call.argument<String>("data")
                    if (data != null) {
                        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(data))
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                        startActivity(intent)
                        result.success(null)
                    } else {
                        result.error("INVALID_DATA", "Data is null", null)
                    }
                }
                else -> {
                    result.notImplemented()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

What am I doing wrong? I don't really know Android and the documentation is confusing me.
